# Display List(of string) content in a label with back/next button functionality

Tags: .net, vb.net

***Initial Situation & Goal:***
I have a List(of String) filled by a streamreader line by line from a .txt file. I created a two button (back and next) form with a label. I want to display the current content of the list in the label with the ability to go back and forth with with the buttons.

***My Code:***

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Public wb As New List(Of String)
Public i As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    btnClose.Visible = False
    btnLast.Visible = False
    lblWort.Text = "Please press Next"
    wb = Wörterbuch.Woerter("C:\Users\Words.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click, btnNext.Click
    'If Next was Clicked
    If sender Is btnNext Then
        btnLast.Visible = True
        'List is not at the end yes
        If i <= wb.Count - 1 Then 'count goes from 1 to 5, i goes from 0 to 4
            lblWort.Text = wb(i)
            i += 1
            'List of Words is at the end
        Else
            lblWort.Text = "Thanks, you finished the test!"
            btnLast.Visible = False
            btnNext.Visible = False
            btnClose.Visible = True
        End If
        'If back was clicked
    ElseIf sender Is btnLast Then
        If i = 0 Then
            btnLast.Visible = False
        Else
            i -= 1
            lblWort.Text = wb(i)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

***My Problem:***
The code runs without error but when I click "back" (`btnLast`) the first time nothing happens. The reason is that because of `i+=1` the counter is already one position to high.

Alternatitvely I could set `i+=1` at:

```
 If sender Is btnNext Then
        i += 1
```

but then I have the problem that the second position in the list is displayed first not the first position as it should be. I have the feeling that there should be a common solution since this must have be applied millions of times but I cannot find it. Anyone who can help me find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put `i += 1` after analysing the given position as far as might provoke the algorithm to ignore the given index (might be taken care of the next time a button is clicked or not). The way to overcome the "starting problem" is setting `i` to -1. That is:

```
If i < wb.Count - 1 Then 'count goes from 1 to 5, i goes from 0 to 4
    i += 1
    lblWort.Text = wb(i)
    'List of Words is at the end
Else
'etc
```

And:

```
Public i As Integer = -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not bring both List.count and i to equal grounds by initializing

```
Public i as integer=1
```

and then adjusting the rest as appropriate

```
If i <= wb.Count - 1 Then
```

Changed to

```
If i <= wb.Count Then
```

etc.

Comment: Do you know that `i = 1` refers to the second position in the list, don't you? Also that the maximum index in the list is `wb.Count - 1` and thus if you try `wb(wb.Count)` you would get an error. Also I understand that you are aware of the fact that, even in case of ignoring these two issues (what, on the other hand, is impossible), what you propose delivers basically the same than what the OP's code. Can you please explain the exact point of this answer?

Comment: Have you attempted to edit the OP's code with your solution?! You cannot do that!!! I think that you should take a deep look at the SO help pages and perhaps start asking/learning a bit before answering (you know, some people here is a bit picky and expect answerers to know what they are talking about at all). As a personal comment (so far was objectively speaking), I have to add that your behaviour is impressive(ly bad): doing something completely pointless (on various fronts), having someone explaining it to you and showing a so (dis)respectful attitude (not changing anything nor answering).

Comment: ehh ? sorry i didnt have much of an idea how lists work and answered it without thinking much.. btw your ans seems to work. and yea i got a lot to learn

Comment: You are in .NET. All the collections in .NET (arrays, lists, dictionaries, etc.) start from zero and thus the last index equals the length of the given collection (wb.Count in this case) minus 1. Learning is easy if you have the right attitude. But, as said, if you are not sure about something, you shouldn't answer; people here expects to get answer from someone knowing what they talk about. I guess that like you: imagine that you come here to ask about a problem and you get a bunch of answers which deliver even more errors than what you originally had. Take it easy and you will enjoy SO a lot